# Regex match two values in nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js

I am new to regex. I have been stuck with this and couldn't find a way to figure this out.

I am using a nodejs in back-end. There is an output to clear things up with regex,

```
results: ["Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x1.data.","  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 2.067",
"Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x2.data.","  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 1.670",
"Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x3.data.","  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 1.686",
"Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x4.data.","  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 0.287"]
```

I need the path ( "/path/x1.data", "/path/x2.data", etc. ) for all x1.data, x2.data, etc. For each x1.data, x2.data, ... there is a corresponding "representations" value. Paths need to have these values. In other words, I need the following:

/path/x1.data => 2.067

/path/x2.data => 1.670

/path/x3.data => 1.686

....................  =>  ......

Comment: What exactly is the format of your input?

Comment: This is a result from nodejs python-shell module. Couldn't understand what the format is this.

Comment: Is the input the JS array after `restuls: ` in your first snippet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var input = ["Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x1.data.", "  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 2.067",
             "Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x2.data.", "  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 1.670",
             "Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x3.data.", "  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 1.686",
             "Comparing /path/uploads/vector-1474379968511.data with /path/x4.data.", "  + Squared l2 distance between representations: 0.287"];

var output = {};
var findPath = / with (.*)\.$/, findValue = /(\d+\.\d+)$/;
var path, value;
for (var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++) {
  path = input[i].match(findPath)[1];
  i++; // move to next item
  value = input[i].match(findValue)[1];
  output[path] = value; // store however you like
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Put this in a runnable snippet and test it

Comment: `console.log(output[path]);` returns these values.


`2.067
1.670
1.686
0.287
`


OK that's great but I need to match these values with x1.data x2.data xn.data ... Like these:

`/path/x1.data => 2.067
/path/x2.data => 1.670
`

Comment: @mertcihan: What does that mean?

Comment: I've just seen your last update `console.log(output)` yes this is just working fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

[`/^([^ ]+) => (\d+\.\d+)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/cO1rY0/2)

The "g" (global) flag means the regex can match more than once. The "m" (multiline) flag means that instead of `^` and `$` matching the start and end of the entire string, they match the beginning and end of a line.

- `^` Start of line
- `([^ ]+)` Matches all non-space characters, one or more times. The brackets mean it will be captured as its own "group" for you to use later.
- `=>` Literal text
- `(\d+\.\d+)` Matches one or more digit (0 - 9). Then a literal dot ".". Then one or more digit (0 - 9). Again, it's captured as its own group.
- `$` End of line

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Oh, okay. Pretty unclear what the input is. And they just wanted "regex" according to the tags, but maybe they need actual code, too.